# Trying to write a mySQL query to get all data from users with a 'CA' post code

Tags: mysql

Two example rows of a table is given below, I am trying to filter out all rows without a `CA` in the postal address.

---

[image]

---

Here is the code so far:

---

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE PostalAddress LIKE 'CA' ORDER BY UserName ASC;
```

Comment: Why aren't you storing the address in parts vs as a long string?  You're gunna cause yourself all sorts of problems doing it that way.

Comment: @MasonStedman I didn't write the tables like that, it's just what i've been given by someone in my team. I just have to create queries.

Comment: Are you looking for CA rows or non-CA rows? `LIKE` with no wildcards (`%`) will match the exact string. `SELECT * FROM User WHERE PostalAddress LIKE '%CA%' ORDER BY UserName ASC;`

Comment: @BenHarris I actually did try that but for some reason SQL fiddle doesn't return anything, it passes without error but nothing shows up.

Comment: You should break out your addresses into separate columns so that this query isn't as clunky. Anyone on "Carolina Street" is going to get hit by this match.

Comment: @tadman Yeah I realise that, unfortunately I can't change the database. I thought there may be a way around this but perhaps not without improving the data layout.

Comment: You can't reliably extract address information from this in the database. You need a parser that can understand the components and identify matches, and that's way more complicated than you should do with a SQL query.